# Lebesgue integrability VS "finite-power" signals

Tags: improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

To keep it simple, I suggest we focus on **real** functions in this question.

I have heard only of 3 definitions of integrability:

- Riemann integrability
- Darboux integrability
- Lebesgue integrability

I am interested here in improper integrals i.e. integration over **unbounded (infinite) intervals**, so only **Lebesgue** is concerned. Let us assume the integration interval is $ \!R = ]-\infty,+\infty[ $.

The convention used is:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f = \lim_{a\to-\infty , b\to+\infty}\int_a^b f
$$
...that is, if the limit does exist.

One may think that a function $f$ would be called "integrable" when its improper integral is finite i.e. $ |\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f| < +\infty $. But I believe that is an accepted definition.

However, I know that the function $f$ is called *absolutely integrable* or *Lebesgue integrable* (or $L^1$) when:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f| < +\infty $$

In signal processing, signal $s$ is said to be *finite-energy* when:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|s|^2< +\infty $$
Seems to me its exactly the definition of a *square integrable* (or $L^2$) function. So far so good.

Now here is the gist. In signal processing, signal $s$ is said to be *finite-power* when:
$$ \lim_{T\to+\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}}|s|^2 < +\infty $$

This is a different kind of improper integral as it is not a limit with two **independent** boundaries $(a,b)$ since they both depend on $T$.

So, my point is, more generally, what about functions such that:
$$ \lim_{a\to+\infty}\int_{-a}^{+a} |f| < +\infty $$

Are they classes of improper integrals in mathematics? If not, would not it have made sense to extend the concept of integrability for these functions?

EDIT1: See accepted answer about this.

EDIT2: I was actually wondering, in which cases we get $ \lim_{a\to+\infty}\int_{-a}^{+a} f $ is convergent but $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f $ is divergent. Does it only happen with odd functions?

Comment: Edit 2.  It is certainly not limited to odd functions.  Take any example of this, and add any integrable function to it to get another example.

Comment: Interesting! By the way, seems that this kind of integral may be called "Cauchy Principal Value" according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the two boundaries are not independent is irrelevant, since the integrand is positive.  If $f \ge 0$, then
$$
\lim_{a\to-\infty , b\to+\infty}\int_a^b f
= \lim_{b\to+\infty}\int_{-b}^b f
$$

**finite power**
The main difference, though, is the factor $1/T$.  In the case of "finite power", it could be that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |s|^2 = \infty$ as long as $$\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{+\frac{T}{2}}|s|^2$$ does not grow too fast.  Growth is allowed to be at most $O(T)$ as $T \to \infty$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Fair enough, since $|f|$ cannot be an odd function, we don't have cases like $\int sin$. I just added a variant of the question, if you're still interested.